# How to read the first (and only) line of a file, split it into separate strings and append it to variables using csh?

Tags: sed, awk, grep, csh

I need some help with the following problem. I just can't figure it out (and yes I did the googlework etc).

Using csh I need to read one line from a file (there is only 1 line in the file), split it into separate strings (!not every value is separated with a space, however they do have a fixed position (always in the 3rd and 4th field)) and assign two of them to two separate variables in long format (so no E+04). The two values of interest are:

```
82390.43500000000 
 and
4.167000000000000
 (so without the 'Earth' attached to it).
```

They need to be assigned to respectively `time` and `time_step`.

The inputfile *temp.txt* looks like:

```
000520000001  260026 8.239043500000000E+04 4.167000000000000E+00Earth Centred Rotating                                          -9.999999999999998E+03-9999999.9999999-9999999.9999999-9999999.9999999
```

There are multiple files called *temp.txt*, however placed in different folders. The only part that stays constant in all files is *Earth Centred Rotating*.

What is the best way to do this (awk/grep/sed/?)?

Thanks!

Comment: But... if you think of your `temp.txt` files, will the 2 values always be in the same "position" in the file? Given you example, I would call the values being in the 3rd and 4th Fields, or could it 5th and 9th in another file? (Please update your question with information and don't respond as a comment ;-) Good luck.

Comment: The first rule of C shell programming is "Don't"!

Comment: Solved it using bash instead of (t)csh :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{sub(/E.*/,"",$3); print$3}' temp.txt
```

and

```
awk '{sub(/E.*/,"",$4); print$4}' temp.txt
```

gives 82390.43500000000 and 4.167000000000000 respectively which can then be assigned to your variables.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it returns an empty line. And when I try to assign it: set var = `awk '{sub(/E.*/,"",$3); print$3}' temp.txt` and echo $var >> log.txt it returns ^^^_^T.